# Error with DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources when installing grpcio

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools, grpcio

I have python 3.12,1 installed and working in a venv

pip is at 23.3.2
setuptools is at 69.0.3

I get a failure when installing grpcio-1.57.0. The output is shown below. Any help would be appreciated!

```
pip wheel --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 "grpcio (==1.57.0)"
Collecting grpcio==1.57.0
  Downloading grpcio-1.57.0.tar.gz (24.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 24.7/24.7 MB 110.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      <string>:43: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/richard/headcoach/headCoach-backend/backend-1/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/richard/headcoach/headCoach-backend/backend-1/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/home/richard/headcoach/headCoach-backend/backend-1/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6dp2h0u2/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6dp2h0u2/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6dp2h0u2/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6dp2h0u2/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 292, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 226, in check_linker_need_libatomic
        File "/usr/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "/usr/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1950, in _execute_child
          raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c++'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have googled the issue and according to a number of sources this hsould not occur with the versions of pip and setuptools that I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version you are trying to install [grpcio 1.57.0](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/1.57.0/) doesn't support python 3.12.1. You can either [install the stable release (grpcio 1.60.0)](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/) which supports python 3.12 or downgrade your python version to 3.11 to use the older version of the package.